# Are there examples of Einstein manifolds with unbounded curvature?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Are there any known examples of Einstein manifolds $(M, g)$ such that $$\sup_{x \in M} \|\text{Rm}(x) \| = \infty$$
I'm looking for these examples because they might provide a counter-example to a problem of mine, but I can't think of any. Obviously such a manifold can't be compact (and therefore it can't be complete with positive scalar curvature) but I haven't been able to think of any concrete example.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek By Myers's theorem, a complete Einstein manifold with positive scalar curvature is compact.

Comment: For what it's worth, Traizet https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.3389 used gluing techniques to show there is a complete embedded minimal surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with unbounded curvature.  This suggests there may be an Einstein four manifold with unbounded curvature.

Comment: Apparently there are incomplete examples. Do you want it to be complete?

Comment: @DeaneYang yes, but I'd be interested in knowing the incomplete examples too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't care about completeness, here's a fairly simple way to construct such examples:  Start with a compact Einstein manifold $(M^n,g)$ with Einstein constant $1$ (i.e., $\mathrm{Ric}(g) = (n{-}1)\,g$) that is not conformally flat.  Now take the sine-cone, i.e., $\bigl(M\times(0,\pi),h\bigr)$ where $h = \mathrm{d}r^2 + (\sin r)^2\,g$.  Then one easily computes that this is also an Einstein manifold with Einstein constant $1$, i.e., $\mathrm{Ric}(h) = n\,h$, but the Weyl curvature of $h$ (which is nonzero since $g$ is not conformally flat) blows up as $r$ approaches either $0$ or $\pi$.

(Also, if one just takes the ordinary cone, $\bigl(M\times(0,\infty),h\bigr)$ where $h = \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2\,g$, then $h$ will be Ricci-flat, but the Weyl curvature of $h$ will blow up as $r\to 0$.)

Finally, as Anton Petrunin pointed out in the comment below, if $(M,g)$ is complete and Ricci-flat (i.e., Einstein with Einstein constant 0), but not conformally flat (equivalently, not flat), the Riemannian manifold $\bigl(M\times\mathbb{R}, h = \mathrm{d}r^2 + \mathrm{e}^{2r}\,g\bigr)$ will be a complete Einstein manifold with Einstein constant $-1$ whose Weyl curvature has unbounded norm as $r\to-\infty$.

Comment: Warped product of Ricci-flat manifold with $\mathbb{R}$ for exponential function produces complete  Einstein manifolds with unbounded curvature --- am I right?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:  That's correct (assuming that the original Ricci-flat manifold is not actually flat).  I will add that to the answer (and credit you for the observation, of course).